# Showing that the average of the derivatives = 0

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to show that if $f$ is a differentiable function where $f'$ is integrable and $f(a) = f(b)$ where $a < b$, then the average of the derivative of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is $0$.

It makes sense to me that if $f$ was increasing, then it must decrease so that $f(a) = f(b)$, and vice-versa. I'm just not sure how to formally prove it. I was thinking about introducing some point $c$ where $c\in(a,b)$, then show that $\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}$ is equal to $-\frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c}$

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

This is just the fundamental theorem of calculus: since $f'$ is integrable,
$$\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx = f(b)-f(a) = 0$$
and thus the average value, which is $1/(b-a)$ of that, is also $0$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove that something is "the average," first you need to have a definition of what the average is.

My definition of the average of a function $g$ over an interval $[a,b]$ would be 
$$
\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b g(x) \,dx.
$$

In your question, the function is $g=f'.$
Plug it in and integrate.

Turning to your question about finding $c,$ if we take a value $c$ such that $a<c<b,$ then
$$f(c)-f(a)=-(f(b)-f(c))$$
because of the condition $f(a)=f(b)$ given in the question. 
In order to have 
$$\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} = -\frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c},$$
we need either to have $c-a = b-c,$
which happens when $c$ is exactly halfway between $a$ and $b,$ or we need to have $f(c)=f(b)=f(a).$

There may not be any number $c$ such that 
$a<c<b$ and $f(c)=f(b)=f(a),$
and even if there is, once we find it we have split the problem into two copies of the exact same problem, which we are not any closer to solving. 
On the other hand, there is always a value of $c$ halfway between $a$ and $b,$ so we can choose that value. Then we will have split the problem into three problems: finding the average derivative between $a$ and $c,$ finding the average between $c$ and $b,$ and combining the averages of the two intervals. I would combine the two averages by solving the original problem, so I think this way makes a lot of extra work that does not get us closer to a proof.